# Run function Parallel using multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

Trying to run functions parallel 3-4 times using multiprocessing:

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Process
import random

def tick(set):
    i = 0
    while True:
        print(f"Tick {set}")
        i += 1
        time.sleep(random.randint(1,3))
        if(i > 5):
            break

def tick_B():
    i = 0
    while True:
        print("Tick B")
        i += 1
        time.sleep(random.randint(1,3))
        if(i > 5):
            break

def tick_C():
    i = 0
    while True:
        print("Tick C")
        i += 1
        time.sleep(random.randint(1,3))
        if(i > 5):
            break

def tick_D():
    i = 0
    while True:
        print("Tick D")
        i += 1
        time.sleep(random.randint(1,3))
        if(i > 5):
            break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    def runInParallel(*fns):
        proc = []
        for fn in fns:
            p = Process(target=fn)
            p.start()
            proc.append(p)
        for p in proc:
            p.join()

    runInParallel(tick("0") , tick("A") , tick_B , tick_C , tick_D)
```

This gave me result:

[image: result]

The code executes first tick(set) and then run parallelly other functions. How to make tick(set) also run in parallel with others.

Comment: when you use parenthesis after name of the function you are calling it to execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tick("0")` and `tick("A")` are invoked before the call to `runInParallel` and returns `None` to `runInParallel`. If you want to invoke function with parameters you need to add the `args` parameter to `Process`. You can send a tuple of function and argument where you want and check it inside the function

```
def runInParallel(*fns):
    proc = []
    for fn in fns:
        if isinstance(fn, tuple):
            p = Process(target=fn[0], args=fn[1])
        else:
            p = Process(target=fn)
        p.start()
        proc.append(p)
    for p in proc:
        p.join()

runInParallel((tick,"0"), (tick, "A"), tick_B, tick_C, tick_D)
```

Output:

```
Tick D
Tick C
Tick A
Tick 0
Tick B
Tick 0
Tick A
Tick C
Tick D
Tick B
Tick D
Tick C
Tick 0
Tick A
Tick B
Tick DTick CTick 0Tick A
Tick B
Tick A
Tick B
Tick DTick C
Tick 0
Tick C
Tick A
Tick D
Tick 0
Tick B
```

Comment: What if my set is list like `(tick,[0,1,2,3,4,5])` like this till 50?

Comment: it say *takes from 0 to 2 positional arguments but 50 were given*

Comment: simply this worked:-- `args=[fn[1]]` , but want to be sure if its correct

Comment: @koceca this will work, you can also send the arguments as `tuple`, `(tick, ([0,1,2,3,4,5],))` (notice the extra comma after the list).